# Rename Attribute value in Time Dimension in SSAS

Tags: ssas

I am working on SQL Analysis service to provide ad hoc reporting in my application. I have created a time dimension to use in my cube. It has some predefined attributes. e.g. Month of year. It is having values like Month 1, Month 2, etc. while I want January for Month 1, February for Month 2, etc...

Can any one please suggest me some work around it??

As I am newbie to SSAS, Sorry if I am missing something very silly....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you work with attributes in SSAS, there are two properties that affect the members of that attribute. The first property - which is set by default when you create the attribute - is KeyColumn. The column that you use here determines how many members are in the attribute because processing generates a SELECT DISTINCT statement based on this column. It's a good idea if you use an integer value here for better performance.

It sounds like perhaps you have a month number for your attribute here, which is good. Except that you want to display a month name. In that case, you set the NameColumn property with the column in your data source view that contains the month name. This produces the label that you see when you browse the dimension.

That said, it's usually not a good idea to have just a month number or month name because you probably want to create a hierarchy to roll up months by year and you won't be able to do that with just a month name. I wrote a blog post describing how to set up a date dimension that might help you: http://blog.datainspirations.com/2011/05/11/sqlu-ssas-week-dimension-design-101-2/

Comment: Hi Stacia, I really appreciate your help. But, the actual problem with me is I have created time dimension using 'Generate a time table in datasource' option. I am not having my custom defined time table. So, can you help me how will I be able to modify in that auto generated table. I can't see that auto generated time table in my datasourceview.

Comment: It sounds like you did not use the Generate Schema option when you used the wizard. You need to go to the Database menu (on the Visual Studio menu bar) and select Generate Relational Schema. That will add the table to your DSV and then you can make the changes to your dimension.